# Restrict access of public classes out of umbrella framework

Tags: ios, swift, ios-frameworks

I have an swift umbrella framework (FrameworkA) which have two sub frameworks (FrameworkB and FrameworkC). FrameworkA uses some public classes defined in sub frameworks(FrameworkB and FrameworkC).

---

```
    umbrella FrameworkA:
        FrameworkB:
            public PubliclyExposedClassB
            public InternallyExposedClassB
        FrameworkC:
            public PubliclyExposedClassC
            public InternallyExposedClassC
```

---

I want to use both the classes of both sub frameworks in FrameworkA.
But want to restrict exposing InternallyExposedClasses outside of FrameworkA i.e. I don't want that external application(importing FrameworkA) can access InternallyExposedClasses of sub frameworks.

How can I achieve this restriction in umbrella framework in swift? All framework are built in swift.

Any hint or tips will welcomed.

Comment: too vague to say anything specific